# regex backwards search

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am using following regex to get `<%? imagepath;%>` from the string, and it is giving correct results

```
<%(\?|.|\s)*%>

<img src="http://abc/xyz/<%? imagepath;%>.gif">
<img not_src="http://abc/xyz/<%? imagepath;%>.gif">
<img src="<%? imagepath;%>_second.gif">
<a href="<%?imagepath%>/abc.htm"/>
```

but, I need only those IMG tags, in which SRC attribute value has `<%?imagepath%>`.

In my case, i am getting all IMG and ANCHOR tags, and I am expecting only first and third IMG tags, because, second IMG Tag's "imagepath" value is in "not_src" attribute, and fourth ANCHOR tag's "imagepath" is in HREF attribute.

Answer (score 2):

Extend the regex you currently use, a match the strings you need:

```
(\ssrc="<%(\?|.|\s)*%>"))
```